# Delphi - TUpdateObject versus OnUpdateRecord for a join SQL statement

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firebird

I have a pFibdataset(which is working similar to BDEDataset) in which I need to make the following join selection

```
select table.Name as name,
table1.Name as name_1,
table2.Name as name_2
from table 
left join table table_1 on table.id=table_1.id
left join table table_2 on table.id=table_2.id
```

Fields name, name_1 and name_2 are linked to some data-aware edits. Now, I want after I'm modifying(update,delete,insert operations) the name,name_1 and name_2 fields to be updated in the tables. Based on the [wiki Using_Multiple_Update_Objects_Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Multiple_Update_Objects_Index) I can use UpdateObjects, or [OnUpdateRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TBDEDataSet.OnUpdateRecord) event.

The problem is that I don't understand how this need to be implemented. I have the join select on the query, how I need to define and work with name_1 and name_2 fields. Can someone provide me an example for this?

I know how to use subqueries in order to accomplish this. I need to see how can I can make it by using UpdateObjects or OnUpdateRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TpFibUpdateObject works like a trigger on client side. To make it work, set the following properties:

```
DataSet - dataset (master) to monitor
KindUpdate - Insert/Update/Delete - action to monitor
SQL - command to execute when action is fired, params are taken from DataSet
ExecuteOrder - AfterDefault/BeforeDefault - probably you need after / master
```

BUT, instead using a lot of UpdateObject components and such tangled approach, I recommend two alternative (read better) ways:

1. Updatable view. It will work like a "virtual table". Create a view that joins these theee tables and write Before Insert/Update/Delete triggers. In Delphi use it as a regular table: select from view / insert into view / update view and delete from view. Anyway I suppose you need in many places these tables linked toghether.
2. Use EXECUTE BLOCK statements in your TpFIBDataSet SQLs. Insert / Update / Delete in a batch all tables.

Comment: +1 for the solution. Problem is that I need 1,2 or 3 fields at the same time. So, it exists a base sql which is getting field name, and after that one or two joins for the other 'name' fields. I also was thinking on the ExecuteBlocks. I will give a try

Comment: Execute Block works for Firebird 2, so maybe you have another version installed. As a workaround you can create the stored procedure and call it from UpdateSQL.

Comment: @Marcodor - can you post an example?

Comment: execute block (OLD_ID integer = :OLD_ID, NAME varchar(100) = :NAME) as begin update TABLE T set T.NAME = :NAME where T.ID = :OLD_ID; end   Sorry, written directly here, without checking.

Comment: Marcodor - I need an example in the FibPlus components. This is my main problem. I know how to write the SQL for execute block, the problem is the dataset.sqls.updateSQL does not work with execute block

Comment: @Marcodor - I BELIEVE you. I just need a full example on how to do it. No errors occurs. I just need a full tutorial, example on how a query/dataset containing a join SQL, updates something through dataset.sqls.updateSQL really updates a table.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : OnUpdateRecord it must be created an TUpdateObject for each field from the joined table.

```
 UpdateObjectvariable.DataSet := Dataset;
 fill the SQL text
 Apply.
```

After all update objects are set,  `UpdateAction := uaApplied;` must be called.

Comment: Marcodor - can you explain me why?